# Unable to run AxoGraph v1.7.6 on macOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: data, software, electrophysiology, analysis

After a recent MacOS update, I am no longer able to run the (latest) AxoGraph software for electrophysiology data analysis on my computer, as I get the following error message:

```
"AxoGraph.app" needs to be updated.

The developer of this app needs to update it to work
with this version of macOS. Contact the developer for
more information.
```

Screenshot:
[image]

I understand that this is because AxoGraph is a [**32-bit application**, which is not supported by macOS Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208436). I have already contacted the support of the application for advice. In the meantime, **is there any good solution besides switching to a different software?**

Comment: I don't have a good solution for you, but in solidarity, I would note that I still have a (network-isolated) machine running Windows XP due to the lack of a software update for my patch clamp hardware (and lack of success running in any sort of 'compatibility mode'). I hope you can find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

## Response from AxoGraph Support

I received an answer from John of AxoGraph suggesting to follow the steps outlined in [this tutorial](https://au.pcmag.com/vmware-fusion-8-for-mac/63913/how-to-run-32-bit-apps-in-macos-catalina) to set up a virtual machine (VM) on my computer with an earlier version of macOS using the **Parallels** software ($79.99/year).

He also discouraged using **VirtualBox**, the free VM manager, as "there's more work involved, and it’s not so smoothly integrated with Catalina." In his reply, John also promised "to finish the new completely re-written 64-bit version of AxoGraph," which "is not far from completion," first releasing a new data-acquisition-only version, subsequently followed by an update with data analysis features. It sounded like all of this would take at least several months, though.

---

## My Solution

After some digging, setting up a virtual machine (VM) with an earlier version of macOS indeed did seem to be the best option for me at this point. What I was after, however, was a **free solution** - and eventually, I managed to get a **Mojave VM** to work on my Catalina using **VirtualBox**. Getting through the whole process was a patchwork of several different sources (mostly following [this tutorial and its comments](https://appletoolbox.com/need-to-run-32-bit-apps-on-macos-catalina-use-a-mojave-virtual-machine/)), so I decided to re-write the **detailed steps I took below** (some steps may be adjustable but I used these specific settings with success):

#### 1. Download macOS Mojave Installer:

1. Go to this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210190
2. Click on *Get macOS Mojave* in step 4, and open in **App Store**.
3. Click on *GET* - that will open the updater, which will download the installer (if you already have Catalina installed, the "update" will stall after the download automatically)
4. Find it in your **Applications** folder as *Install macOS Mojave.app*

#### 2. Create an ISO installation media using Terminal:

1. Create a temporary disk image from the install file & make a bootable installer using Terminal:

   ```
   hdiutil create -o /tmp/Mojave.cdr -size 7000m -layout SPUD -fs HFS+J
   ```
2. Attach that file, with Terminal command:

   ```
   hdiutil attach /tmp/Mojave.cdr.dmg -noverify -mountpoint /Volumes/install_build
   ```
3. Build it, with command:

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/install_build
   ```
4. Move it to your mac’s Desktop:

   ```
   mv /tmp/Mojave.cdr.dmg ~/Desktop/InstallSystem.dmg
   ```
5. Unmount the file:

   ```
   hdiutil detach /Volumes/Install\ macOS\ Mojave
   ```
6. Convert it to ISO:

   ```
   hdiutil convert ~/Desktop/InstallSystem.dmg -format UDTO -o ~/Desktop/Mojave.iso
   ```
7. Rename it to remove the CDR extension:

   ```
   mv ~/Desktop/Mojave.iso.cdr ~/Desktop/Mojave.iso
   ```
8. Exit Terminal via Terminal command:

   ```
   exit
   ```

#### 3. Create a new virtual machine (VM) in VirtualBox:

1. Download **Oracle's VM VirtualBox Manager** ([https://www.virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) & install it on your Mac
2. Open **VirtualBox**
3. Click on **New**
4. Select *Type: Mac OS X* and *Version: Mac OS X (64-bit)*
5. Memory size: *8192 MB* (at least 3 GB)
6. Hard disk: *Create a virtual hard disk now*
7. Hard disk file type: *VDI*
8. Storage on physical hard disk: *Fixed size*
9. File location and size: *32.00 GB*

#### 4. Tweak the VM before installation:

1. With your newly created VM selected in VirtualBox, go to *Settings* → **Storage**:

   1. Click on *Empty* → Remove [*square with a red cross at the bottom*]
   2. Click on *Controller: SATA* → Add optical drive [*CD with a green plus sign*] → *Add* → Find the .iso file you created and click *Choose*
2. *Settings* → *Display*: **Video Memory** - at least *128 MB*
3. *Settings* → *System*: **Processor(s)** - at least *2*

#### 5. Install the macOS on your VM:

1. With your VM selected in VirtualBox, click *Start*
2. Wait until the *Language* selection appears; select your preferred language and continue
3. *macOS Utilities*: **Disk Utility** → Continue
4. Select *VBOX HARDDISK Media* → click on **Erase** in the toolbar
5. Name the drive as you wish and keep the default selections: *Format: Mac OS Extended (Journaled)* and *Scheme: GUID Partition Map*; click *Erase*
6. *Quit* Disk Utility when done
7. Select **Install macOS**, *Continue*, and *Agree* to the license
8. Select the hard drive you just erased and **Install**
9. MacOS starts installing; wait and **be patient**! (It took about half an hour for me. The VM may restart at least once in the process.)
10. Go through the **MacOS setup** (select your Country, keyboard, etc.)

    - It is recommended that you do not log in with your Apple ID at this time and click *Set up later* instead
    - I also did not allow *Location Services*, nor *data collection* from Apple
    - Once installed, you can eject the installation disc from within the VM
    - It also might be a good idea to go to *System Preferences...* → *Software Update* → *Advanced...* → uncheck *Check for updates*

#### 6. Install the latest version of AxoGraph on your VM:

1. Open **Safari** within your VM
2. Go to https://axograph.com/download
3. Click on **Mac OS X 10.4 and up***
4. **Install** AxoGraph

> ## Voilà!
>
> ***Now you can run AxoGraph, as well as other 32-bit applications, on your MacOS Catalina!***

- You should be able to turn off the VM from within, as you usually would shut down your Mac
- It is booted again by selecting your VM in VirtualBox and clicking *Start*

Comment: Thanks for the thorough update!